# LSTM: doesn't forget gate interfere to input gate?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I need to implement an LSTM, so I'm reading [a tutorial of how does it work](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/). Quoted *(the relevant parts; if you're aware of LSTM internals, you're probably want to just skip down to the question, and then look at any picture)*:

> The first step in our LSTM is to decide what information we’re going
>   to throw away from the cell state. This decision is made by a sigmoid
>   layer called the “forget gate layer.” It looks at $h_{t−1}$ and $x_t$,
>   and outputs a number between $0$ and $1$ for each number in the cell
>   state $C_{t−1}$. A $1$ represents “completely keep this” while a $0$
>   represents “completely get rid of this.” [image: forget gate]
>   …
>
> The next step is to decide what new information we’re going to store
>   in the cell state. This has two parts. First, a sigmoid layer called
>   the “input gate layer” decides which values we’ll update. Next, a tanh
>   layer creates a vector of new candidate values, $\tilde{C}_t$, that could be
>   added to the state. In the next step, we’ll combine these two to
>   create an update to the state. [image]
>   …
>
> It’s now time to update the old cell state, $C_{t−1}$, into the new
>   cell state $C_t$. The previous steps already decided what to do, we
>   just need to actually do it.
>
> We multiply the old state by $f_t$, forgetting the things we decided
>   to forget earlier. Then we add $i_t∗\tilde{C}_t$. This is the new
>   candidate values, scaled by how much we decided to update each state
>   value. [image: input gate]

The problem is that when $f_t$ *(forget gate)* is close enough to zero to drop $C_{t-1}$ *(prev. state)* upon multiplication, then $i_t$ *(input gate)* would also destroy the new state upon $i_t * \tilde{C}_t$, because accordingly to an image $f_t = i_t$.

So, how is the new state supposed to squeeze to the next step? Wouldn't the *new state* be forgotten at the same time with the prev. state? How is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the equations near diagrams, you can see that $ f_t \neq i_t$ because weights($ W_f$,$W_i$) and biases($ b_f$,$b_i$) are not tied together. You can't see them on the diagrams because, yellow rectangles implicitly include them.